# I want to center-align the TextInput label, React Native Paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

How can I center-align the `TextInput` label from the `TextInput` component that comes with the React Native Paper library?

I have tried this:

```
<TextInput
     label={
         <Text style={styles.label}>...</Text>
     }
 />


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    label: {
        textAlign: 'center', 
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] the post to explain why this code does not center-align according to your criteria? Is it missaligned, not displaying at all, does it throw an error ...

Comment: Label is, by default, on the left side of the TextInput, the above code does not seem to change anything. No errors, just not aligned as expected.